# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"controller_name"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I'm always getting this error and I don't understand where I am wrong. I think I have everything I need action in controller, resources in route file and view for controller action.  I put the route `current_events/new` in the browser when I get this error. I also try with just `resources :current_events`

output of `rake routes`:

```
   current_events GET      /current_events(.:format)              current_events#index
new_current_event GET      /current_events/new(.:format)          current_events#new
    current_event GET      /current_events/:id(.:format)          current_events#show
```

`config/routes.rb`:

```
appname::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

  resources :current_events, only: [:show, :new, :index]
end
```

`CurrentEventsController`:

> ```
> class CurrentEventsController < ApplicationController
>
>   def index
>       @current_event = CurrentEvent.all
>
>       respond_to do |format|
>           format.html
>           format.json { render json: @current_event }
>       end
>   end
>
>   def create
>       @current_event = CurrentEvent.new(params[:current_event])
>
>       respond_to do |format|
>           if @current_event.save
>               format.html { redirect_to @current_event, notice: 'current event was created.' }
>               format.json { render json: @current_event, status: :created, location: @current_event }
>           else
>               format.html { render action: "new" }
>               format.json {render json: @current_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
>           end
>       end
>   end
>
>   def new
>       @current_event = CurrentEvent.new
>
>       respond_to do |format|
>           format.html
>           format.json { render json: @current_event }
>       end
>   end
>
>   def edit
>       @current_event = CurrentEvent.find(params[:id])
>   end
>
>   def destroy
>       @current_event = CurrentEvent.find(params[:id])
>       @current_event.destroy
>
>       respond_to do |format|
>           format.html { redirect_to current_event_url}
>           format.json { head :no_content }
>       end
>   end
>
>   def show
>       @current_event = CurrentEvent.find(params[:id])
>
>       respond_to do |format|
>           format.html
>           format.json{ render json: @current_event}
>       end
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: Are you including the id in the link to?

Comment: I forgot to say, I am trying to go to new page so in browser I say current_events/new, I will fix my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I forgot to say, I am trying to go to new page so in browser I say current_events/new

It will still throw an error if there's a link that doesn't work on the page.

In your view, the link should look something like this:

```
<%= link_to "name of current event", current_event_path(@current_event) %>
```

## update

based on your rake routes

```
current_event GET      /current_events/:id(.:format) #note ":id"
```

when you're trying to see a specific current event, you need to pass it an `:id` which makes sense - if you're trying to call a specific person you need to use **their** telephone number.  so your code should look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', current_event_path(@event) %>
```

But keep in the mind that `@event` won't work unless you define it correctly in the controller action for this view.

Comment: Hi, yes I have something similar, I added it to my question <%= link_to 'Back', current_event_path %> Do I need to use the instance variable? If yes, why? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, So I have to specify in controller with a params :id if i want it to link to a specific post

Comment: @NaomiKuntinama, right - just look at the output of rake routes for an idea of what is required

Comment: im not sure I understand completely, now I am trying to fix link for new_current_event_path. I add new_current_event_path(@current_event) but it is a syntax error? can you explain a little how this works?

Comment: check out this 'getting started' guide - i think it will answer a lot of questions for you!  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: if you were curious i was just missing the comma between 'new event', new_current_event_path

Comment: was that in the question?  sorry, should have caught that!